# Как запушить ViewController, при этом разрешив ему использовать различные ориентации экрана?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mwphotobrowser

Для всех `ViewController` в приложении разрешено использовать только портретную ориентацию:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(NSUInteger)allpication:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Однако для одного из `ViewController`, входящего в стек `NavigationViewController`, я хочу при его пуше сделать доступными другие варианты ориентации экрана.

Есть подозрение, что для

```
pushViewController:animated:
```

это не получится.  Только для варианта при

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367703

В частности, я пытаюсь добиться чтобы в `MWPhotoBrowser` можно было поворачивать экран при просмотре полноразмерных фотографий. При этом его подкласс должен обязательно пУшиться...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с ориентацией/поворотом экрана](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520482/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам не запрещать конкретные ориентации в `infoplist`. Создайте 1 рутовый `view controller`, реализуйте в нем метод `-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientation`. В нем пропишите ту ориентацию, которая вас нужна и наслудете все свои контроллеры от него. А тот контроллер, которому хотите дать возможность использовать другие ориентации - не наследуйте от рутового.