# Проблема с ориентацией/поворотом экрана

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, navigationcontroller, mwphotobrowser

В приложении:
`SWRevealViewController` (root) -> `UINavigationController` -> из него пУшатся остальные `ViewController's`

**SWRevealViewController.m** *(разрешаю 3 вида ориентации для всего приложения)*

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

**MYNavigationController.m** *(хочу разрешить **только** портретную ориентацию)*

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Только почему-то потом для всех `ViewController's`, которые пУшатся из `MYNavigationController`, экран можно поворачивать... а нужно только портретную ориентацию!

Так же хотелось бы для одного из `ViewController's` все же разрешить поворот экрана пользователем, причем он так же должен пУшиться, а не отображаться в модальном окне (просмотр фото-галереи через `MWPhotoBrowser`).

Почему не срабатывает `return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;` в `MYNavigationController`, ведь он главный для остальных `ViewController's`?

ps. Во всех ViewController's так же прописывал

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае этот метод будет работать на rootViewController. Если надо учитывать childViewControllers, то в rootViewController надо найти необходимый childViewController и выдать в качестве результата результат его метода.